# Remove duplicates across multiple sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to remove duplicates across 2 different sheets.

I have my active sheet, and I want to remove duplicates that already exist in my sheet "Blacklist". I want to run this process for both Column A and Column B (or simply for any values across the entire sheets). When a duplicate is found, I want to leave the row in tact but replace the value with '' (e.g. an empty cell).

I have a working version I mangled together, but only for the active sheet.

N.B. it's the findDuplicate function that I use, the removeDuplicate function I left there not to mess anything up :)

```
// this is a Google Apps Script project

function onOpen() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var menuItems = [
    { name: 'Find duplicates...', functionName: 'findDuplicate' },
    { name: 'Remove duplicates...', functionName: 'removeDuplicate' }
  ];
  spreadsheet.addMenu('Duplicates', menuItems);
}

function removeDuplicate() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var data = range.getValues();

  var rowNum = range.getRow();
  var columnNum = range.getColumn();
  var columnLength = data[0].length;

  var uniqueData = [];
  var duplicateData = [];

  // iterate through each 'row' of the selected range
  // x is
  // y is
  var x = 0;
  var y = data.length;

  // when row is
  while (x < y) {
    var row = data[x];
    var duplicate = false;

    // iterate through the uniqueData array to see if 'row' already exists
    for (var j = 0; j < uniqueData.length; j++) {
      if (row.join() == uniqueData[j].join()) {
        // if there is a duplicate, delete the 'row' from the sheet and add it to the duplicateData array
        duplicate = true;
        var duplicateRange = sheet.getRange(
          rowNum + x,
          columnNum,
          1,
          columnLength
        );
        duplicateRange.deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
        duplicateData.push(row);

        // rows shift up by one when duplicate is deleted
        // in effect, it skips a line
        // so we need to decrement x to stay in the same line
        x--;
        y--;
        range = sheet.getActiveRange();
        data = range.getValues();
        // return;
      }
    }

    // if there are no duplicates, add 'row' to the uniqueData array
    if (!duplicate) {
      uniqueData.push(row);
    }
    x++;
  }

}

function findDuplicate() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var data = range.getValues();

  var rowNum = range.getRow();
  var columnNum = range.getColumn();
  var columnLength = data[0].length;

  var uniqueData = [];

  // iterate through each 'row' of the selected range
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var row = data[i];
    var duplicate = false;

    // iterate through the uniqueData array to see if 'row' already exists
    for (var j = 0; j < uniqueData.length; j++) {
      if (row.join() == uniqueData[j].join()) {
        // if there is a duplicate, highlight the 'row' from the sheet
        duplicate = true;
        var duplicateRange = sheet.getRange(
          rowNum + i,
          columnNum,
          1,
          columnLength
        );
        duplicateRange.setValue('');
      }
    }

    // if there are no duplicates, add 'row' to the uniqueData array
    if (!duplicate) {
      uniqueData.push(row);
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks so much for your help! I've been at this for a few hours and figured I should just ask the experts for advice :)

Answer (score 1):

The first lines of both your removeDuplicate and findDuplicate function seems indeed to indicate that you refer to the active spreadsheet / sheet / range

```
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var data = range.getValues();
```

If you want to be able to use the same function for a given spreadsheet / sheet / range which is not the active one, you will need to use other functions than the getActiveXXX().

For example, to get the sheet named "Blacklist", you should use 
`sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Blacklist")`
(see also https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)

If you want to access a specific range which differs from the active range, you should use the getRange method (see also https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getrangea1notation)
Note that getRange method can be used in different ways, e.g. 
`getRange("A1:D4")`, `getRange(1, 1, 3, 3)` (the parameters being respectively startRow, startColumn, numRows,numColumns)

Additionally, if you don't want to hardcode the last line of your 2 columns, you will most probably need this function to find the last line in the code :
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getlastrow
(there is also an example there showing how to use getRange() in combination with getLastRow()).

I hope this will help you going further.
Please note that I didn't check the rest of your code and just assumed that your deduplication logic works fine as you mentioned it in your commment.

Good luck !